# Why definition is needed for static constant used in std::make_unique?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, unique-ptr

The following code produces an “undefined reference” [error](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HqQQZriOJDbblf3B) in C++14 mode, and has [no issue](https://wandbox.org/permlink/M3EuKTvgcAYqXN8Q) in c++17 with latest Clang (same for gcc, but works in both cases with VS2017):

```
#include <memory>

struct S 
{
    static constexpr int i = 42;
};

int main()
{ 
    std::make_unique<int>(S::i); // undefined reference in C++14, no issue in C++17
}
```

What is changed between two standard revisions related to this issue? Does VS have correct behavior for this code in C++14 according standard?

Adding a definition for `S::i` fixes the issue for any compiler/standard.

My question is mostly of `make_unique` behavior, why definition is needed? For instance, I can use `std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(S::i))` without definition of `S::i`.

Also, suggested duplicate doesn’t answer why Visual Studio accepts code in C++14 mode.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ my question is mostly of make_unique behavior, why definition is needed? For instance, I can use `std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(S::i))` without definition of `S::i`

Comment: _"my question is mostly of make_unique behavior, why definition is needed?"_ That's kinda kinda completely orthogonal problems. Nothing to do with _implicit inline definition of `static constexpr`_  class members.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it’s not so easy to find the root of the problem while asking until you know the answer.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ the problem is that `std::unique_ptr` is taking references as parameter, which may make ODR use of the `S::i` variable

Comment: @αλεχολυτ _"it’s not so easy to find the root of the problem while asking until you know the answer."_ I didn't knew the answer in advance spotting your question. The first thing I noticed was that you mingled up something regarding the necessity of the `static constexpr` definition and `std::unique_ptr`. My reaction was just to lookup a _"c++ static member definition needed before c++17"_ google search.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Do you know how VS is handling this without references?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ it *may* ODR use the varaible. Depends on some factor including inlining, which remove the need of actual references.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot it seems that msvc implicitly define static member even for `const` (i.e. not `constexpr`). Example code succesfully compiled with [msvc](https://rextester.com/HZWKK40469), but failed with [clang](https://rextester.com/UWPHS91086) or [gcc](https://rextester.com/QRHWL48804) on linker stage.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ it's not safe to assume that msvc does that. It may simply inline it or somewhat don't need definition in that case. Taking the `int` by value is sometimes enough. That would be my bet.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot What do you mean by "simply inline"? For c++17 `static constexpr` is implicitly `inline`, and such inlining means definition IIRC (e.g. variable can be ODR-used). BTW taking an address of variable (see my previoud comment) should require to define it, isn't it?